# iOS share app not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview

all the displays have been set programmatically, 1 question how do I set the following code programmatically as well

```
NSArray *objectsToShare;
        NSString* shareText = @"hey check out this new app on App Store";
        NSURL *website = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s", "http://www.lmg.co.za"]];

    objectsToShare = @[shareText, website];

    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTwitter,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,
                                   UIActivityTypePrint,
                                   UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard];

        activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

       if ([activityVC respondsToSelector:@selector(popoverPresentationController)]) {
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = self.view;
            activityVC.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = [(UIButton *)sender frame];
        }

        [NavigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

please let me know if I should add a separate view controller

thank you in advance

Comment: lol im new to iOS and I have builded a Webview app programmatically now. my question is actually how to take the code above and set it programmatically with out using a story board.

Comment: This above code is always be without storyboard. This is native code work so just call accordingly, it automatically behave in your UI.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Chnage the  below line

```
[NavigationController presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

With

```
[self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString * title =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."];

NSArray* dataToShare = @[title];

UIActivityViewController* activityViewController =[[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:dataToShare applicationActivities:nil];

[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```